# GWT-Log & Jetty: How dynamicially set the SymbolMap path

Tags: gwt, jetty, embedded-jetty

Currently we have the following working example with a messy "war" prefix in path:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gwt-log-remote-logger-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.RemoteLoggerServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>symbolMaps</param-name>
        <param-value>war/WEB-INF/deploy/APPNAME/symbolMaps/</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Jetty is configured, for testing purposes, with WebApp directory "war", because it is a single installation. I tried with /WEB-INF and some other combinations, does not work...

How to set the path independent from installation? So that we do not need to fix it in the build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution if using a own customized build of GWT log. The current version does generic search for the symbolMaps.

See here https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/issues/detail?id=73&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Stars%20Summary